# antiword doesn't work on hosted server

Tags: linux, directory, redhat

I guess it could be a stupid question but it has taken me hours.

On a redhat Linux server, I wrote a webpage which tried to call a software "antiword" which is on the same server.

antiword is located at /home/myusername/bin, and needs directory /home/myusername/.antiword to run.

when I run my webpage in the browser, it searched for /.antiword instead of /home/myusername/.antiword

So it said directory not found.

How do I fixed the problem?

### One thing to clarify

antiword is the program name. no matter where you call it, it will search for a directory ".antiword" at the same location "/home/myusername/.antiword"

btw I don't have the root account, so "ln" wouldn't work.

Comment: How do you know "it searched for /.antiword"? Do you use any environment variable? Share some code.

Comment: Antiword looks for its mapping files in three directories, in the order given:
(1) The directory specified by $ANTIWORDHOME
(2) The directory specified by $HOME/.antiword
(3) Directory /usr/share/antiword

I can set $ANTIWORDHOME, but when I access it thru browser. Will the env var work?

Comment: Apparently HOME is not what you expect it to be unless you access a web page as `.../~myusername/`. Even in that case I'm not confident apache will set HOME (I may be wrong). How do you call antiword?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Hopefully this will prove useful to someone else, because `antiword` is very useful software.

`antiword` does not like hosted web servers for some reason (outlined here: http://foswiki.org/Support/Question638). I encountered this when deploying a `node` server that had worked well on a local QA machine to a production server in the cloud. As such, my solution involves `node`.

This won't work in production:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('antiword /some/word.doc', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stderr);
  });
```

You should see

```
I can't find the name of your HOME directory
```

or something to that effect. The [link](http://foswiki.org/Support/Question638) provided sheds some light on the reason. To solve this problem, I set the `$ANTIWORDHOME` environment variable (as per the [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/antiword.1.html)):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var environment = process.env;
environment.ANTIWORDHOME = '/usr/share/antiword';

exec(command, {env:environment}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
  });
```

Now, if everything is otherwise correct, you will see the results produced by `antiword` and not the error that has been driving me up the wall.

Comment: This one really helped me run the antiword solution on AWS lambda python. 
to do so just set `os.enviorn['ANTIWORDHOME'] = 'path_to_layer_antiword'`